# Как скопировать папку с файлами средствами php с одного места в другое

Tags: ftp, php

как скопировать папку с файлами средствами php с одного места в другое

Comment: По FTP ? []()

Comment: Без разницы на чём, я пробовал с Curl не получилось

Comment: Если Вы умеете скачивать один файл (а такой вопрос Вы задавали ранее), то просто:   
Вариант1. на Сервер1 создаем скрипт, который получив имя папки соберет данные о всех файлах, которые есть в этой папке и вернет их в ответе.  
Сервер2 обращается к этому скрипту, парсит результат и по-одному выкачивает файлы.  
Вариант2.  
на Сервер1 создаем скрипт, который получив имя папки запакует содержимое этой папки в архив.  
Сервер2 выкачивает архив и распаковывает его